# Laravel Yajra DataTable - Fetch content via Ajax with supplied search parameters

Tags: laravel, search, datatable, yajra-datatable

After searching as to how to fill up a Yajra DataTable with data from an ajax call with user supplied search parameters, I came to this [page](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/html-builder-ajax) for the official documentation.

It has a code snippet as follows...

```
$builder->ajax([
    'url' => route('users.index'),
    'type' => 'GET',
    'data' => 'function(d) { d.key = "value"; }',
])
```

However, I cannot make anything out of it. Where does the `$builder` variable come from? How do I use the data received from the Ajax call to fill up the table? This [page](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/html-builder-callbacks) lists the callback functions with no details.

**What I need**

A full-blown example of how to fill up my data table with data received from an Ajax call initiated by the search button `#btn_search` after selecting a value from the drop-down `#param`.

For simplicity, lets assume that the table structure looks like...

```
<select id="param">
    <option value="">Select </option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<button id="btn_search" value="Search">Search</button>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Serial</th>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The controller method that returns the data...

```
<?php

public function getBasicData()
{
    $users = User::select(['id','name','email','address']);

    return Datatables::of($users)->make();
}
```

The user selects a value from the dropdown and clicks on the search button. **In the actual scenario, several dropdowns are there to collect the search parameters**. Relevant jQuery code is...

```
$("#btn_search").click(function() {
    var param_value = $("#param").val().trim();

    //  make ajax call probably 
});
```

How can I make the Ajax call inside the click handler and fill up the data table with the received data?

Answer (score 1):

The $builder variable is the class id of the table that would view the information ,

Here is an example :

```
 <table id="data" class="table table-bordered table-hover" >

     <thead>         
             <tr class="table-head">
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>namr</th>
                            <th>email</th>
                            <th>date</th>
                            <th>auth</th>
                            <th>control</th>
                            <th>control</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>


                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                               <th> </th>                         
                            <th> </th>
                            <th> </th>
                            <th> </th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

and this is ajax code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var lastIdx = null;

    var table = $('#data').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ url('/adminpanel/users/data') }}',
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
            {data: 'admin', name: 'isadmin'},
            {data: 'edit', name: 'edit', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ],

        "language": {
            "url": "{{ Request::root()  }} /admin/cus/Arabic.json"
        },
        "stateSave": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "order": [[0, 'asc']],
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        aLengthMenu: [
        [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
        [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
        ],
    iDisplayLength: 25,
        fixedHeader: true,

        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [{
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "sButtonText": "ملف إكسل",
                    "sCharSet": "utf16le"
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "copy",
                    "sButtonText": "نسخ المعلومات",
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "print",
                    "sButtonText": "طباعة",
                    "mColumns": "visible",


                }
            ],

            "sSwfPath": "{{ Request::root()  }} /website/admin/cus/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },

        "dom": '<"pull-left text-left" T><"pullright" i><"clearfix"><"pull-right text-right col-lg-6" f > <"pull-left text-left" l><"clearfix">rt<"pull-right text-right col-lg-6" pi > <"pull-left text-left" l><"clearfix"> '
        ,initComplete: function ()
        {
            var r = $('#data tfoot tr');
            r.find('th').each(function(){
                $(this).css('padding', 8);
            });
            $('#data thead').append(r);
            $('#search_0').css('text-align', 'center');
        }

    });

    table.columns().eq(0).each(function(colIdx) {
        $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function() {
            table
                    .column(colIdx)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
        });




    });



    table.columns().eq(0).each(function(colIdx) {
        $('select', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('change', function() {
            table
                    .column(colIdx)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
        });

        $('select', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });


    $('#data tbody')
            .on( 'mouseover', 'td', function () {
                var colIdx = table.cell(this).index().column;

                if ( colIdx !== lastIdx ) {
                    $( table.cells().nodes() ).removeClass( 'highlight' );
                    $( table.column( colIdx ).nodes() ).addClass( 'highlight' );
                }
            } )
            .on( 'mouseleave', function () {
                $( table.cells().nodes() ).removeClass( 'highlight' );
            } );


</script>
```

this is a full table with ajax example ,like Yajara documentation help .

Comment: where are the rules specifically  in the Yajra DataTable doumentation ? Do you think it would be easier to use only jQuey dataTable instead of Yajra datatable in this case ?

Comment: where in your code does it take the value of search parameter (i.e. `#param` drop down) to make the search on clicking the search button i.e.  `#btn_search` ?

Comment: with ajax the search begin without clicking the search button and refreshing the page , if you want that just use laravel and jquery .

Comment: you can use this link to train yourself , begin with a small example to understand .

Comment: Does your code take the search parameter to make the ajax call ? ' with ajax the search begin without clicking the search button and refreshing the page' -  what do you mean ? Why to refresh the page ?

Comment: I mean that -> ajax is used to retrieve data from database without refresh the page or clicking search button . it shows the results that meet your query  when you start typing name or words in search text box .

Comment: ' when you start typing name or words in search text box' - but I have a drop down to provide the search parameter ... how to make use of that ?